# how can i release thread with activity finish？

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executorservice

sorry with my poor english：）.
In my APP,there is a `VideoView` to play video(m3u8).
In this `VideoView` activity,i use `Thread` and `ExecutorService(newCachedThreadPool)` to get play URL and other information.
when i want go back to last activity,i do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (videoView != null) {
        videoView.stopPlayback();
        videoView = null;
    }
    if (executor != null) {
        executor.shutdownNow();
        executor = null;
    }
}
```

here is Runnable

```
private Runnable changeSeekBar = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        while (seekBarAutoFlag) {
            if (null != videoPlay.this.videoView&& videoPlay.this.videoView.isPlaying()) {
                video_seekBar.setProgress((int) videoView.getCurrentPosition());
            }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

and excutor like this:

```
executor.execute(changeSeekBar);
```

here is error info
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN8Y0.png)

Comment: to stop thread call this `new Thread(runnable).interrupt();`

Comment: Its not about how to use generally java-threads.
You have error info involving registers. Which means that you have problems with your hardware or some other software or shared library. It's impossible to look into because its on chinese

Comment: thanks~，the title（发送给MIUI）means send an error message to MIUI(a company),i try this,it is work.But there is some error,so i try to use WearHandler.Thank u a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last,i use EventBus replace Thread+Handler,and it's work.

here is EventBus github:https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Thanks a lot for help :)